# Unique constraint with @Embeddable: Cannot resolve passed columnNames

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, hibernate, jpa

I have this `Entity`

```
@Embeddable
data class FooId(
    @Column val identifier: UUID,
    @Column val date: LocalDateTime
) : Serializable

@Entity
@Table(
    name = "foo",
    uniqueConstraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(name = "uniqueIdentifierDateCombination", columnNames = ["identifier", "date"])
    ])
class Foo(
    @EmbeddedId
    val fooId: FooId,
    @Column val description: String,
    @Column val title: String,
)
```

Now this `columnNames = ["identifier", "date"]` does not resolve. It says

> Cannot resolve column 'identifier'

That is probably because the columsn are passed through `@EmbeddedId`.
I tried already `columnNames = ["fooId.identifier", "fooId.date"]` and `columnNames = ["fooId_identifier", "fooId_date"]`. Same result.

How do I pass `columnNames` to a `UniqueConstraint` when the columns in question are within `@Embeddable`?